# Why is this error being given on Mac Mini Terminal? I'm trying to change my mac address on my mac mini

Tags: zsh, bypass

|  xargs  sudo  ifconfig  en0  ether
zsh: no matches found: ‘s/(..)/1:/g
usage: rand [-base64 | -hex] [-out file] num
-base64            Perform base64 encoding on output
-hex               Hexadecimal output
-out file          Write to the given file instead of standard output
zsh: no such file or directory: s/.$//’
jndiptikundaikar@Dipti-Phone ~ %

Why this error occurring? I'm trying to change my MAC address on a Mac mini using the console (to bypass parental router controls on spectrum internet). Could u plz help me change it along with other tips to change my mac adress to sucesffully bypass the system? (I don't know much about coding)

|  xargs  sudo  ifconfig  en0  ether
zsh: no matches found: ‘s/(..)/1:/g
usage: rand [-base64 | -hex] [-out file] num
-base64            Perform base64 encoding on output
-hex               Hexadecimal output
-out file          Write to the given file instead of standard output
zsh: no such file or directory: s/.$//’
jndiptikundaikar@Dipti-Phone ~ %

after typing this code in openssl rand –hex6 | sed  ‘s/(..)/1:/g; s/.$//’  |  xargs  sudo  ifconfig  en0  ether

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is that the `-hex6` part of what you're trying to run is not an available command. You have the option of `-base64` or `-hex`.

Here's a more up to date and better tutorial: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/change-mac-address-on-mac/